Change column name at a particular position using python
I would like to change the names in the excel file using python.
example; cell
A3 id -> sample_id
B3 singal-> DBS VCA Signal
How can I do this in python? i have tried doing using the pandas library.
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('filename')
column_position = 1 
new_column_name = 'sample_ID'
df.columns.values[column_position] = new_column_name
df.to_excel('modified_excel_file.xlsx', index=False)


What do you mean by "names"? If the cells are "A3" and "B3", they are in the header, right?

Why use Pandas and not just edit the Excel file directly using Openpyxl?

Change the cell values using Openpyxl.
Writing new values will just overwrite the old
from openpyxl import load_workbook


excel_file = 'foo.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(excel_file)
ws = wb['Sheet1']

ws['A3'].value = 'sample_id'  # Set the value for cell A3
ws['B3'].value = 'DBS VCA Signal'  # Set the value for cell B3

wb.save(excel_file)




column_name_mapping = {
    'column_name': 'new_column_name'
}

df.rename(columns=column_name_mapping, inplace=True)



Use the above approach
